# How to post text to template using PHP SDK?

Tags: php, docusignapi

We have created template via the web interface.

In template we add two text fields!

We follow  DocuSign PHP SDK, and we receive test email, but without populated document.

**PHP code:**

```
$templateRole = new  \DocuSign\eSign\Model\TemplateRole();
$templateRole->setEmail("example+11000@email.com");
$templateRole->setName("NN");
$templateRole->setRoleName("Boss");

// custom textTabs
$templateRole->setTabs([
    "textTabs"=>[
        [
            "tabLabel"=>"\\*TextDate",
            "value"=> "24/10/18"
        ],
        [
            "tabLabel"=>"\\*TextName",
            "value"=> "my text"
        ]
    ]
]);
```

**log:**

```
POST https://demo.docusign.net:7801/restapi/v2/accounts/42****/envelopes

TraceToken: d357c21d-60f3-*********************
Timestamp: 2018-10-23T10:09:07.5516969Z

Content-Length: 356
Content-Type: application/json
Accept: application/json
Host: demo.docusign.net
User-Agent: Swagger-Codegen/2.0.1/php
X-DocuSign-Authentication: {"Username":"ms@*********.com","Password":"[omitted]","IntegratorKey":"[omitted]"}
X-DocuSign-SDK: PHP
X-SecurityProtocol-Version: TLSv1.2
X-SecurityProtocol-CipherSuite: ECDHE-RSA-AES256-**********
x-forwarded-for: 213.61.************

{"emailSubject":"[DocuSign PHP SDK] - Signature Request Sample","status":"sent","templateId":"cca2833f-de76-****************","templateRoles":[{"email":"np@**********.com","name":"NN","roleName":"boss","tabs":{"textTabs":[{"tabLabel":"\\*TextDate","value":"24/10/18"},{"tabLabel":"\\*TextName","value":"my text"}]}}]}
201 Created
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
X-DocuSign-TraceToken: d357c21d-60f3-477d-**************

{
  "envelopeId": "6833c3dc-e2e3-407e-*****************",
  "uri": "/envelopes/6833c3dc-e2e3-407e-*****************",
  "statusDateTime": "2018-10-23T10:09:07.0830000Z",
  "status": "sent"
}
```

**UPDATE**

- We created / upload template in appdemo
- We add text fields via admin interface
- we want to populate this text field when run php script (docusign-php-client) or using simple CURL scripts from api documentations.
- when run php script, we send email, but in document is not populated our text fields.

How to setup this php client to add our text in uploaded template?

**Any idea?**

Answer (score 0):

Look at the signature of the setTabs() method, an \DocuSign\eSign\Model\Tabs is expected.

- @param \DocuSign\eSign\Model\Tabs $tabs

  ```
  $tabs = new \DocuSign\eSign\Model\Tabs();
  $tab = new \DocuSign\eSign\Model\Text();
  $tab->setName('my_field');
  $tab->setTabLabel('My Label');
  $tab->setAnchorString('my_anchor_string');
  //or
  $tab->setXPosition(100);
  $tab->setYPosition(100);
  $tab->setPageNumber(1);

  $tabs[] = $tab;
  $templateRole->setTabs($tabs);
  ...
  ```

Comment: I updated my answer to be more clear. Witch method you can't find ?

Comment: Class 'DocuSign\eSign\Model\TextTab' not found

Comment: My bad, it's DocuSign\eSign\Model\Text not DocuSign\eSign\Model\TextTab.

Comment: Sorry, but not work. We also tested with Postman, and not work.